# Removing specific item from nested array and saving the result, how to make this code cleaner

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written this code where i know the the specific item i want to remove (`timeslot`) and the company to which that specific item belogs to (`name`)

My data looks like this:

```
this.state.data = [
  {name: :name1', times: [timeslot1, timeslot2, timeslot3]},
  {name: :name2', times: [timeslot1, timeslot2, timeslot3]},
  {name: :name3', times: [timeslot1, timeslot2, timeslot3]},
]
```

Is there a way to make this code cleaner? i feel its a bit to verbose or redundant:

```
  deleteTime (timeslot, name) {
    const newState = this.state.data.map(company => {
      if (name === company.name) {
        let newTimes = company.times.filter(time => {
          return time.dateUTCString !== timeslot.dateUTCString
        })
        company.times = newTimes
        return company
      }
      return company
    })
     this.setState({data: newState}) 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mutate company in the map function, if you optimize your app and use Pure component (extend from PureComponent or use react.memo) then your component won't re render when you mutate the changes.

Here is how you could write what you did in a shorter way and without mutation:

```
//destructure dateUTCString as that's all you are using
deleteTime({ dateUTCString }, name) {
  this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.map(company =>
      name === company.name
        ? {
            ...company,//copy company
            times: company.times.filter(//reset times
              time => time.dateUTCString !== dateUTCString
            ),
          }
        : company//return original company
    ),
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have different timeSlots in times array,

You can use `splice` function to remove element at an index where data matches in array:

```
deleteTime (timeslot, name) {
    const newState = this.state.data.map(company => {
      if (name === company.name) {
        company.times.splice(company.times.indexOf(time), 1);
      }
      return company
    })
     this.setState({data: newState}) 
  }
```

Comment: Mutating is not a good idea, if OP uses pure components the component indicating the change won't re render.